# Is Pegging permissible in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, sexuality

I know that anal sex is totally forbidden in Islam. It is clear that a husband can insert a finger in her wife's vagina.

Inserting a finger in the back passage is allowed by some scholars but mostly said no. So my question is about pegging?

***Can a wife wear a strap-on herself and insert this into husband's back passage with his permission???***

Please answer only Muslims and give your answer with its reference whether it is yes or no?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing that directly addresses this issue because these kinds of strange inventions did not exist in the past. However, by analogy and deductive reasoning based on Islamic texts (anal sex haram, homosexual behaviors haram, impurity haram), it is clear that what you describe is not appropriate because if it is not Halal for a man to enter a woman then why would it be OK with a reversal of genders? Generally what Islamic guidance is given for men also applies for women as well.. UNLESS there is evidence it is Halal for women specifically (e.g., silk, gold, etc). In this case, there is no evidence women can do this to men. So it is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Most scholars seem to say the reason why anal (where the woman is the receiving partner) is not allowed in part because of the bodily contact with najaasa. Nothing forbids inserting things that aren’t body parts into the anus, so I would assume pegging is Halal. I haven’t heard this directly from someone with Islamic credentials, though, I just put the pieces together and made an assumption.

Answer (score -2):

I live in Iran and I think it might be because god didn't create anything without using it and I like it myself and in a man but its good to relax a bit and be the pray for once at least. It's not like I'm a demon or think like demon or wear like them.

Answer (score -2):

I say no because, yes god invented us to love and do anything but then it sent us its book and said the things that is bad and good for us its like a story that gives us step by step of our lives. And I hate pegging because why should woman peg men to show some men how to respect woman, they can teach them we are humans we have brains.